# Finding the linear transformation with only two vectors

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

Let $T\colon\mathbb{R}^3\to\mathbb{R}^{2}$ a linear transformation such that
$$T(3,2,1)=(1,1)$$
$$T(0,0,1)=(0,0)$$
I have to find $T(x,y,z)$.

It's clear that $(3,2,1)$ and $(0,0,1)$ are linear independent. However, since the dimension of $\mathbb{R}^{3}$ is three, they don't span it. Hence, I'm not able to write $(x,y,z)$ using only these two vectors.

How should I proceed?

Comment: Your analysis is correct. There is no way to determine the value of $T$ on a general vector in $\Bbb R^3$. Perhaps there was a little more information?

Comment: There is actually a $3$-parameters family of solutions to this problem

Answer (score 0):

You can map a parameter that defines the line between the points.

$$ A(t) = (1-t) \pmatrix{3 \\ 2\\ 1} + t  \pmatrix{ 0 \\ 0 \\ 1} $$

and

$$ A' (t) = (1-t) \pmatrix{ 1 \\ 1}  + t \pmatrix{ 0 \\ 0} $$

and in the plane, there is a defined perpendicular direction such that

$$ A' (t,u) = (1-t) \pmatrix{ 1 \\ 1} + u \pmatrix{ \mbox{-}1 \\ 1} $$

and in 3D use the cross-product to get a perpendicular direction that corresponds to one possible solution

$$ A(t,u) = (1-t) \pmatrix{ 3 \\ 2 \\ 1}  + t \pmatrix{ 0 \\ 0 \\ 1} +u \pmatrix{ 2 \\ -3 \\ 0} $$

this results in

$$ A' = \pmatrix{x' \\ y'} = \pmatrix{ \frac{1}{13} & \frac{5}{13} & 0 \\ \frac{5}{13} & \mbox{-}\frac{1}{13} & 0 } \pmatrix{x\\y\\z} = \pmatrix{ \frac{x+5y}{13} \\ \frac{5x-y}{13} } $$ when $A = \pmatrix{x\\y\\z}$

This is a result of the parametric relationship for $A(t,u)$

$$ \left. \pmatrix{ x = -3 t + 2 u + 3 \\  y = -2 t - 3 u + 2 \\ z = 1} \right\} \Rightarrow \pmatrix{ t = \mbox{-} \frac{3x+2y-13}{13} \\ u = \frac{2x-3y}{13} }  $$

which is solved for $(t,u)$ and placed in the parametric relashipship for $A'(t,u)$.

Comment: I find your notation quite confusing, since I'm used to $A$ for a matrix. Nevertheless, you should clarify that this is one *possible* solution. We could specify $T(\vec v)=0$ for $\vec v$ in *any arbitrary plane* containing the $z$-axis and not containing $(3,2,1)$.

Comment: @TedShifrin - sorry for the confusion. I prefer the parametric relationship because I understand the 1:1 relationship between coordinates better as they correspond to the same parameter values. In any case, I have made some updates above that might help clarify a bit how I see this problem.

Comment: I appreciate the answer however I believe it misses some information. There should be a third vector, then a basis for $\mathbb{R}^{3}$ such that I'd be able to solve it.

Comment: I am curious to see what other post as answers